# Can't connect to Postfix/Dovecot with Airmail.app but I can with Mail.app (Connection refused?)

Tags: postfix, dovecot

So I installed Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL as per [this guide](https://library.linode.com/email/postfix/postfix2.9.6-dovecot2.0.19-mysql):

Uses encryption and only SSL and seems like a newbie way of going secure from the beginning, but I have a problem. For an odd reason I am able to use Mail.app on OS X successfully to send and receive emails but with Airmail, I can't. I just get connection refused on the App and the following error on my server:

```
Jul 16 15:35:26 apple dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=my@email, method=PLAIN, rip=xxx, lip=xxx, mpid=31389, TLS, session=xxx
Jul 16 15:35:26 apple dovecot: imap(my@email): Disconnected: Logged out in=24 out=707
Jul 16 15:35:26 apple postfix/smtpd[31390]: connect from unknown[xxx]
Jul 16 15:35:27 apple postfix/smtpd[31390]: disconnect from unknown[xxx]
Jul 16 15:35:46 apple postfix/smtpd[31372]: disconnect from unknown[xxx]

$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = sub.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,
permit_mynetworks, 
reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains =
mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps =
mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Comment: It's probably a configuration option you need to set, what options does Airmail present to you in terms of session encryption?

Comment: Only PLAIN and CRAM-MD5, but I even enabled CRAM-MD5 in Dovecot, it tries to login that way but it says the user and password are incorrect. If I use plain it says it just had connection refused.

Comment: So you have `auth_mechanisms = plain login cram-md5` ?

Comment: In airmail are you using `fulltls` or `tls` ?

Comment: Correct @NickW, I tried both, neither have worked.

Comment: I agree with ALex, it seems like airmail isn't doing something right in the process, you should usually have a line before the login talking about the TLS session being started IIRC

Answer (score 1):

PLAIN/CRAM-MD5 it just method of authentication. As I see from the guide, they have used

```
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
```

that mean you MUST use SSL/TLS to get authentication to work. You can just disable those restriction (set it to no) or enable ssl/tls in Airmail

Comment: Ok, so it does work if I disable TLS auth only, but why? I am using TLS in Airmail, I want to keep the security on.

Comment: I can't answer "why". You could try to increase debug level in postfix with debug_peer_list/debug_peer_level options and try again. One more thing, could you show the output of postconf -n

Comment: Went ahead and added that on my main post.